# Know which line was clicked within the php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a while loop in php that returns me some data from my mysql database,

This loop creates several ul dynamic read that return me the lines surveyed in the bank,

each row returns 1 button and a imput type hidden that contains a link its value,

I would like to know the link for each button clicked.

for example the list returns me 10 lines

each line will have a hidden imput with the value of a link

I wonder what is the link home value so I click the button btlink

```
Example

<Ul>
    <?php while ($ videolist = $ resultvideos-> fetch_array ()) {?>
    <Li>
        <Ul>
            <Li class = "listdivvideos">
                <Button class = "btlink" id = "btlink"> </ button>
            </ Li>
            <Li>
                <Input type = "hidden" class = "linkvd" value = "<? Php echo $ videolist [ 'link']?>"> </ Input>
            </ Li>
        </ Ul>
    </ Li>
</ Ul>
<? Php}?>
```

I tried using this code but it just returns me the first link

```
$('.listdivvideos').on('click', function(){
      var linkdovideo = $('.linkvd').attr('value');
      alert(linkdovideo);
});
```

Comment: Note: `input `elements are [**void elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), `</input>` is always incorrect. If you're using HTML, just write `<input ...>`. (If you were writing XHTML, you'd write `<input ... />`, but you aren't.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you don't need input elements for this, you could do something like this:

```
<?php while ($ videolist = $ resultvideos-> fetch_array ()) { ?>
<li>
    <button class="btlink" data-value="<?php echo $ videolist['link'] ?>">Click me</button>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

And then in your jQuery code:

```
$(".btlink").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data("value"));
});
```

Comment: Absolutely, if those inputs aren't used for anything else (and without names, that seems likely).

Comment: Quibble: Unless the OP really needs the features of `data`, it's overkill to just retrieve a single attribute: `.attr("data-value")`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you explain why `data` is overkill and why you wouldn't use it in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @BorisSavic: `data` initializes jQuery's data cache for the element, looking through all `data-*` attributes, parsing their values, and adding them to that data cache, which is then kept as long as the element exists. If the goal is just to get the `data-value` attribute, there's no need to do all that and keep the result in memory, just `.attr("data-value")` is all we need. (Minor quibble on a good answer.)

Answer (score 4):

[Boris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37940159/157247) is by far the best approach if you can change the structure. *(Except I wouldn't use `.data` there.)*

If you can't, you're not too far off:

```
$('.btlink').on('click', () => {
// ^^^^^^^--- (1)
    var linkdovideo = $(this).closest("ul").find(".linkvd").val();
// (2) -----------------^     ^             ^               ^
// (3) ----------------------/             /               /
// (4) -----------------------------------/               /
// (5) --------------------------------------------------/
    alert(linkdovideo);
});
```

1. Handle the click on the button, not the `li`.
2. `this` is the `button` that was clicked.
3. Then we go up to its `ul` via `.closest("ul")`.
4. Using `find` lets us find the `.linkvd` **within** that `ul`.
5. `.val()` gets its current value. With `input` elements, you almost never want `.attr("value")` because that isn't the *current* value of the element, it's the *default* value of the element. (Confusing, I know.) Now, it would work here if you never change that value in code, since it's a hidden element, but in general it's best to get in the habit of using `.val()` with inputs.

---

Side note: Note: `input`elements are [**void elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), `</input>` is always incorrect. If you're using HTML, just write `<input ...>`. (If you were writing XHTML, you'd write `<input ... />`, but you aren't.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.listdivvideos').on('click', () => {
  var linkdovideo = $(this).find('.linkvd').attr('value');
  alert(linkdovideo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is not a direct relation between the button and the hidden input except that they're in the same ul container, you can do this:

```
$('.listdivvideos').on('click', '.btlink', function {
    var link= $(this).closest('ul').find('.linkvd').val();
    alert(link);
});
```